# Visual Studio 2013 compiler crash for alias template

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013

Recently I've written some code compilation of which resulted in crash window with message "compiler driver has stopped working". The minimal code which still reproduces this crash follows.

```
namespace _private_
{
    // Using SFINAE to figure out the return type of T::operator[]. 
    // If T does not have operator[], then class T itself is used,
    // so that return type of T::operator[] is calculated as
    // type = esists(T::operator[]) ? typeof(T[0]) : T;
    struct SquareBracesReturnType
    {
    private:
        template<class T>
        static decltype(std::declval<T>()[0])    test(T* t);

        template<class T>
        static T test(...);

    public:
        template<class T>
        using type = decltype(test<T>(0));
    };
}


template<class TArray>
using SquareBracesReturnType = _private_::SquareBracesReturnType::type < TArray > ;

template<class TArray, class TSubArray = SquareBracesReturnType<TArray>>
struct ArrayTypeTraits
{
    using SubArrayTypeRaw = TSubArray;
    using SubArrayType = typename std::remove_reference<SubArrayTypeRaw>::type;
    using SubarrayTypeTraits = ArrayTypeTraits < SubArrayType, typename SquareBracesReturnType<SubArrayType> > ;
    using ArrayType = TArray;
    static const size_t nDim = 1 + SubarrayTypeTraits::nDim;
    using ElementType = typename SubarrayTypeTraits::ElementType;
private:
    template<class T, class TArg>
    static TArg dummyFunc(SubArrayTypeRaw(T::*)(TArg));
public:
    using IndexType = decltype(dummyFunc(&TArray::operator[]));
};

template<class T>
struct ArrayTypeTraits < T, T >
{
    using ArrayType = T;
    static const size_t nDim = 0u;
    using ElementType = T;
};

template <class TArray>
using IndexTypeOf = typename ArrayTypeTraits<TArray>::IndexType;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     ArrayTypeTraits<vector<double >>::IndexType j = 3u; // line 1
     IndexTypeOf<vector<double >> i = 3u;                // line 2
     double d = 0.0;                                     // line 3
     //d = i; // <-----uncomment this to break compiler  // line 4

     return 0;
}
```

To observe the crash the line marked as `line 4` should be un-commented. But even with this line commented while debugging it becomes obvious that compiler fails to figure out the type of `i`. All the variables in watch window are empty which indicates that something is wrong. Commenting the `line 2` remedies the situation. This is really strange, as types of `i` on line 2 is the same as type of `j` on line 1. Lines 1 and 2 are actually completely equivalent.

Comment: I think you are missing some include files or something, because g++ spits out a few dozen errors about missing this, that the other.

Comment: If you get a compiler to crash, that's a bug in the compiler. No question.

Comment: I get the same thing in VS2013. Definitely a compiler bug. You should report it on Connect.

Comment: Yes, compilers should not crash even when you feed them "rubbish", never mind for correct code (the "elbow-test" used to be a popular test for software stability - that is, put your elbow on the keyboard, multiple times if required).